# How to use ViewBag in Kendo Grid ClientTemplate's If condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am loading some ids to a `ViewBag` to use it's data in the related View.

```
var userAccountList =serviceResponse.RoleList.Select(x => x.RoleId).ToList();
ViewBag.UserRoles = userAccountList;
```

this result is a `List<string>`.

In the View a Kendo Grid retrieves data from json.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RoleModel>().Name("KendoGrid").Scrollable().Columns(columns =>
 {
        columns.Bound(x => x.Id)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;"})
            .ClientTemplate("# if ( Id != '3'){
                #<a class='k-button' href=\"/Role/Delete/#= Id #\"><span class='k-icon k-delete' style='pointer-events: none;'></span>Delete</a># }#")
            .Width(85).Sortable(false)
            .Hidden(!((BaseController)this.ViewContext.Controller).UserHasPermission(PermissionType.RoleDelete));
        columns.Bound(x => x.Name);

....
 }
```

When I use static values such as `'3'` I could prevent to show `a` tag that was used as delete button. How can I use `ViewBag.UserRoles` in this conditional if the list contains `Id` that's bound to column?

Comment: What I do is pass the values from the controller to the view's model. Then add a hidden input (HiddenFor). Now you can create a jquery function like GetId that returns `$('#myHidden').val()`. Then `# if ( Id != GetId())...`

Comment: thx. the way that you say exactly have done what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in order to use Razor you would have to do something like that

```
.ClientTemplate("# if ( Id != "'+ @ViewBag.UserRole +'")
```

If we were talking about one string value.
Now for your case you could use Template instead of ClientTemplate with something like this

```
.Template(
    @<text>
         @if (ViewBag.UserRoles.Any(u => u == item.Id))
         {
            ... add your link
         }
   </text>
```

A couple more examples you can find in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463143/define-a-template-column-for-telerik-mvc-grid-in-razor-syntax).
Most probably it has documentation too by I couldn't find what I was looking for at the moment.

Comment: calling a js function have done it. I have a little complicated client and header template so I did not to prefer such a way like this. I will try this later for a simplier sample. thx for explanation.